# Validating a Windows Identity out of process

Tags: .net, security, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication

I have an intranet application developed with Windows Authentication. I have the need to interact with a Unix application and want to be able to pass through security information, such as a token in addition to the Identity name when calling the service.

The reason for this is that the external service must validate the security context before it proceeds. Ideally this would be done by LDAP, but can be another external .NET application that it trusts if this is not supported by LDAP.

Validating the user name alone is not enough, I need to get a security related token which I can independently verify belongs to the specified user.